# Angular 1.5 sort in <select ng-options>

Tags: angularjs

I have seen similar posts on stack overflow but I have tried them all and can't seem to get it working.

I want to sort my angular dropdown list alphabetically but for some reason it doesn't understand the "|orderby:" filter.

My code is as follows:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-
model="widget.documentSelectedGroupName.groupName" 
id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="group as group.groupName for group 
in widget.GroupNameSearch 
| orderBy:group.groupName track by group.mailNickname">
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try orderBy:'group.groupName'

Comment: Use `| orderBy:'groupName'` instead

Comment: DevQon's answer worked. I still don't understand why we use groupName instead of group.groupName. could you please elaborate a little bit? Nonetheless thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add extra `group` there. Just simplt try:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="widget.documentSelectedGroupName.groupName" id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="group as group.groupName for group in widget.GroupNameSearch | orderBy:groupName ">
```

You can't combine `track by` and `as` in `ng-options`.